# Azure Sentinel RBAC permissions

Tags: azure

This is a question regarding the setup we have with our azure sentinel instance its only visible to the global admin that set it up and not to other global admins .So how do I as the second global administrator  get to see  the azure sentinel instance , log analytics workspace and resource group ? As at the moment I can only see the subscription .

Answer (score 0):

A global admin does not necessarily have access to all Azure Subscriptions.
I guess Sentinel was created in a subscription where your account does not have access.

Ask your other global admin to add you to the subscription/resource group, or you can gain access this way.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin

Comment: The azure sentinel instance and the resource groups that I cannot see are definitely within the same subscription with two resource groups that I can also see  when I go above the subscription I cannot  see the management group so try the instructions in the link above and update you